# How to avoid jerk when notifyDataSetChanged method of adapter is called?

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-listview

I am trying to add pagination in my listView.

I added a method in my custom BaseAdapter which adds next page results at top of list on scroll to first item in list.

```
public void addEntriesToTop(List<ChatModel> entries) {
// Add entries to the top of the list
this.chatMessages.addAll(0, entries);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

So if I have to add next page on top of ListView, I am using like this in my activity.

```
//result contain new items to be added to top of list
adapter.addEntriesToTop(result);
//so that list scroll sets to last visible message to user
final int index =  result.size();
listView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                             //go to user's last scroll position
                              messagesContainer.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
                                }
                            });
```

This method is working fine and retains user's last scroll position. But it has a problem, when I call addEntriesToTop() it scrolls the ListView to bottom(because of notifyDataSetChanged() ) and then when I call setSelectionFromTop it scrolls to user's last position. In this transition, there is small jerk.

Please help me to smooth this transition.

Thanks

Comment: i know you would be looking for solution within listview but try to use recyclerview it has methods like notifiyiemrangeinserted(...)
there will be no "jerks" in recyclerview

Comment: I hope I could change my listView to recycleView but I can't.
Suggest something in listView?

Answer (score 0):

> As ListView is old and now its obselete, now you can use Recyclerview
>   instead of ListView, here is the link that helps you to convert your
>   ListView to RecyclerView. RecyclerView have many methods to add your custom animations and also it have not any jerks while adding/removing items.

[Replacing ListView with RecyclerView](https://traversoft.com/2016/01/31/replace-listview-with-recyclerview/)

> For Default Animations you can use this link:

[RecyclerView Animations – Add & Remove Items](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-animations-add-remove-items/)